# None regular width for more than six list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have some problem with my jquery, i need to set up function for two kinds of list. First if elements in this list lenght 6 or less, second when it's more than 6. So i have this function but it's not working, can u help me?

```
if (
   $('.producer_other_articles ul').children('li').length < 7) {
   $('.producer_series_info').css('width','390px');
}
else {
   $('.producer_series_info').css('width','980px');
}
```

Comment: arent you missing the if statement condition part?

Comment: probable formatting issue of 'if' condition?

Comment: the code looks fine - define "not working"

Comment: the first condition is warking but second not...

Answer (score 0):

Try [`size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

```
if (
   $('.producer_other_articles li').size() < 7) {
      $('.producer_series_info').css('width','390px');
}
else {
   $('.producer_series_info').css('width','980px');
}
```

Comment: I know they are the same, the OP could try using `.size()` and check if it works.

Comment: it'll make no difference `.size()` just returns `.length`.  The problem lays elsewhere.